# Android JSON data parsing

Tags: android, json

I got big problems with parsing JSON data. I am always getting this eror:

```
error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.Lang.String cannot be       
converted to JSONObject
```

I need to get JSON data and list it in a ListView. I need to list a name, last name, number and a picture, so I would be very grateful for some suggestion about loading images from url, but now the main problem is that i am always getting that error i mentioned.

here's the code, JSONParsing.java:

```
public class JSONParsing extends ListActivity {
private static String URL = "http://androidtest.apiary.io/get-users";

private static String TAG_USERS = "users";
private static String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static String TAG_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
private static String TAG_PH_NUM = "number";

JSONArray users = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
                                                                          String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject jobj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        users = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++){
            JSONObject job = users.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String name = job.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String lastName = job.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
            String number = job.getString(TAG_NAME);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_LAST_NAME, lastName);
            map.put(TAG_PH_NUM, number);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME + " " + TAG_LAST_NAME, TAG_PH_NUM }, new
                             int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

And JSONParser.java:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

And the xml's, list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".JSONParsing" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".JSONParsing" >


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your json.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you are getting String along with your object which can most probably be an error which is thrown by server side scripting. That string cannot be converted to json object. Make sure it doesn't throw any error. If you want me to clarify much about this, just print this `System.out.println(sb.toString());`  immediately after this piece of code in your **JSONParser** class and let me know.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json from the link you have posted

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Hyper",
            "last_name": "Active",
            "image": "http://thehyperactive.com/logo.png",
            "number": 098423239
        },
        {
            "name": "Igor",
            "last_name": "Švehla",
            "image": "http://www.webstrategija.com/ws/adminmax/images/upload/10/igor_svehla_web.jpg",
            "number": 098523239
        },
        {
            "name": "Hrvoje",
            "last_name": "Horvat",
            "image": "http://www.rhein-neckar-loewen.de/images/spieler_2010/hrvoje-horvat.jpg",
            "number": "098423240"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ivan",
            "last_name": "Aksijentijevič Podvorski",
            "image": "http://dalje.com/slike/slike_3/r1/g2009/m02/x213194805338620316_1.jpg",
            "number": 098423241
        },
        {
            "name": "Gasper",
            "last_name": "Sōtsy",
            "image": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/pub/image-0em6ZpPcOdZ5lNMcu6cP5vOTrPiLzZFqRDckeCHGr4zB-2pG0emkiNscr_KvzvxVejSB/gasper-sopi.jpg",
            "number": 098423242
        }
    ]
}
```

Try the below

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://androidtest.apiary.io/get-users");
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
 HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
 String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
 Log.i(".......",_response);
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);
 JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("users");
    for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);
        String name = jb.getString("name");
    }
```

You should use asynctask and do your network related operation in `doInbackground`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I tried and the snap on my phone

[image]